# How can I stabilize a BasicEditField contentHeight?

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry

I'm working on a GUI having some BasicEditFields.

The screen has several Manager's, ButtonFieldss, LabelFields and so forth.

After changing the text of the field, getContentHeight() returns a larger value. (37 with some text, 38 with other text)

I have specified padding and font, but the content height changes with the text field.

Is there any way to have a fixed size for my BasicEditField that will not vary according to the text content?

Note getPreferredHeight() returns the a constant value of 37, according to the font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by subclassing editfield and overriding sublayout:

```
        protected void sublayout(int w, int h){
            super.sublayout(w, h);
            setExtent(w, yourFixedHeightHere);
        }
```

I'm not sure if the call to `super` is needed.

Comment: Actually, sublayout is for Manager sub-classes. However, the same technique works fine calling Field.layout( int w, int h ). Note that without calling super.layout(w,h), the text does not get drawn. So I guess we have to call super.layout(w,h);